# Factory girl association self referencing the parent model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, integration-testing, factory-bot

In my application an account can have a single owner (user) and multiple users.

In my tests I do this:

```
# account_factory_static.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :account do
    name 'demoaccount'
    association :owner, :factory => :user
  end
end

# user_factory_static.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    email 'demo@example.com'
    first_name 'Jon'
    last_name 'Doe'
    password 'password'
  end
end
```

and use them like below:

```
let(:account) { FactoryGirl.create(:account) }
```

The problem is that right now`account.users.count` equals `0` because I have no way to do something like `@account.users << @account.owner` like I do in my controllers when a user signs up.

The question is how can I add the associated account's id to the account_id attribute of the user in FactoryGirl?

In other words how do you do it in FactoryGirl?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you, please, provide an information about associations between these models? Does `account` has not only an `owner` but also kind of `has_many :users`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `after :create` block for it:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :account do
    name 'demoaccount'
    association :owner, :factory => :user

    after :create do |account|
      account.users << account.owner
    end
  end
end
```